# URL : How to add multiple Query String within Source Query String?

Tags: splistitem, url, query-string

I have a simple question regarding the &Source Query String in SharePoint 2007, which normally SharePoint used in on List Item page, when click on "Close" button, it can redirect back to the listing page.

My objective is to do add in multiple Query String after the Source, example as below:

```
/DispForm.aspx?ID=1&Source=/Pages/AllItems.aspx?QueryStringA=XXXX&QueryStringB=YYYYY
```

After click on "Close" button, it redirect to

```
/Pages/AllItems.aspx?QueryStringA=XXXX
```

the QueryStringB was missing, guess it is treated as another Query String same level as Source instead of the Query String within Source.

Any workaround on the issue above? please help...

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Guys, I found the answer, the ampersand should encode into %26 and it works~!!

Comment: Please post and mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

the ampersand should encode into %26

Answer (score 2):

instead of

```
&
```

use

```
&amp;
```

this will surely help